# Homology of knot complement in an arbitrary $3$-manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, knot-theory

Let $K$ be an oriented knot in an oriented $3$-manifold $M$. Let $\nu(K) \approx S^1 \times D^2$ denote the tubular neighborhood of $K$ in $M$.

If $K$ is null-homologous, i.e., $[K]=0$ in $H_1(M)$, then **why** this implies that $$H_1(M \setminus int(\nu(K))) \cong \mathbb Z \oplus H_1(M).$$

**P.S.** I applied the Mayer-Vietoris argument to the pair $(\nu(K), M \setminus int(\nu(K)))$, so we have the following sequence: $$\ldots \to \underbrace{H_1(S^1 \times S^1; \mathbb Z)}_{\cong \mathbb Z ^2} \to \underbrace{H_1(\nu(K); \mathbb Z)}_{\cong \mathbb Z} \oplus H_1(M \setminus int(\nu(K); \mathbb Z) \to H_1(M; \mathbb Z) \to \ldots$$

I cannot effectively use the assumption that we have a null-homologous knot $K$ in $M$.

Comment: To get you started: the condition that $K$ is null homologous implies that the inclusion-induced map $H_1(\nu K) \rightarrow H_1(M)$ is the zero homomorphism. This will allow you to replace the segment of the exact sequence you have written with one of the form $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow H_1(M\setminus \nu K) \rightarrow H_1(M)$.

Comment: I agree with your first sentence. Could you elaborate on why does it imply the second one?

Comment: You can decompose $H_1(S^1\times S^1)$ as the direct sum $\langle \mu \rangle \oplus \langle \lambda\rangle$, where $\mu$ is the class of a meridian and $\lambda$ is the class of a null homologous longitude. The subgroup  $\langle \lambda\rangle$ maps isomorphically onto $H_1(\nu k)$ factor in the exact sequence from Mayer-Vietoris. This means you can quotient $\langle \lambda\rangle$ and  $H_1(\nu k)$ from the exact sequence whilst still preserving an exact sequence.

Comment: Admittedly there is some algebra hidden in this step.

Comment: I see... I am not capable of doing algebra great! How about looking at chain levels in the Mayer-Vietoris sequence? Respectively, say $f$ and $g$. Then the maps are of the form: $f(x)=(x,-x)$ and $g(y,z)=y+z$.

Comment: Certainly, examining the form of those maps is part of it. The point is that the subgroup $H_1(\nu(K))$ is in the kernel of one map and hence in the image of the incoming map.

Comment: I can write up an answer at some point -- I just don't quite have the time to do it right now...